# CSS: Using line-height for vertical centering without giving a fixed height. Is there a way?

Tags: html, css

I often use line-height for vertical centering the text within a inline-element.

I have made this demo:

```css
body,
section {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightGrey;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 48px;
}

.my-element {
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="wrap">
    <span class="my-element">My element</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Works fine. The text is exact vertically centered within the grey bar.

But the Problem with this approach is: I got to use the height of the parent-element and put it fixed in there.

**Is there a better, a more dynamic approach, when using this pattern.**

So that it doesn't become broken when the height of the parent-element changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center text with CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865458/how-to-vertically-center-text-with-css) and [Vertically align text in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div) and others found by searching SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Flexbox and set `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center` for both vertical and horizontal center.

```css
section {
  background-color: lightGrey;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="wrap">
    <span class="my-element">My element</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the height functions. After doing this there will be no space between the span and div. So you add a padding. `padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;` Which I have used below, you could even use something like `padding: 10px;` to be less specific.

```css
body,
section {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightGrey;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="wrap">
    <span class="my-element">My element</span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `transform: translate`, and the dupe link has many more ways

```css
body,
section {
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  background-color: lightGrey;
}

#wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 48px;
}

.my-element {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="wrap">
    <span class="my-element">My element</span>
  </div>
</section>
```